# How to check if a string variable contains negative value or not in java

Tags: java

I need to put a constraint for negative values on string variable. For Eg :--

```
string zeroval = "0.0000"
String x = "";
if (x==null) || (x.equals(zeroval)) { // code which checks if string x has 0 or null value
              x = "--"                // replace it by --
}
```

similarly i want to add another piece of code which checks if String x contains any negative values (for eg : `"-0.025"`) and replace it by --
The above String x should not contain null/zero/negative values

Please help

Note :- In order to add negative value check convert the string to float as i cannot use pattern matching technique for eg:- x.equals("-")

Answer (score 6):

Is your input data always meant to contain valid numbers? If so, you could just use:

```
 BigDecimal number = new BigDecimal(text);
 if (number.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) <= 0) {
     text = "--";
 }
```

This will validate that it really *is* a number as well as performing the check. Additionally:

- It copes with other representations of 0, e.g. "0.00", "0", "+0"
- It uses `BigDecimal` to avoid oddities in binary floating point representations (e.g. a very small positive value being seen as 0). Unlikely to be a problem, but fundamentally you've *got* decimal data, so you might as well parse it that way.

Comment: if (number.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) <= 0) {
when i use this statement i'm getting a compile time error saying BigDecimal.ZERO cannot be resolved

Comment: @user1466466: That's odd. Is the rest of BigDecimal working for you? BigDecimal.ZERO was introduced in 1.5 - what version of Java are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to Integer or double using wrapper class.

```
String number="12.3434"
if(Double.parseDouble(number)<0)
//do stuff here
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the string starts with a "-":

```
if (x==null) || (x.equals(zeroval) || x.startsWith("-")) {
  x = "--";
}
```

I can't help but feel you are doing something ill-advised by using Strings to represent numerical data.

Comment: Well there are classes like BigDecimal that are designed for the sole purpose of representing numbers. You should try and parse them in early as BigDecimal, and perform any logic on those, rather then on the raw String.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Double.parseDouble(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29) or [`Float.parseFloat (String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#parseFloat%28java.lang.String%29). These methods will help you get a `double` or a `float`, respectively.

After this, you can easily check if the value is negative.

Comment: float f = Float.parseFloat(String)                                  Float f = Float.valueOf(String) .....can u tell me which of the above techniques are more suitable for my problem ??

Comment: @user1466466 the 2 methods (`parseFloat` and `valueOf`) are identical/synonyms. You can use either one.